# На странице личных сообщений о причинах бана не переведён текст

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, личный-ящик

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст:

> If the moderator team is unable to address your concerns, please
>   contact the Stack Overflow team.

В трансе строка с ключом [2cbb886e3a2d1e0eaa1cf367560bc779](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/146638149?q=key%3A2cbb886e3a2d1e0eaa1cf367560bc779).

Comment: Я думал, вы уже завязали...

Comment: @alexolut я только начал ٩(◕‿◕｡)۶

Comment: @alexolut вообще, довольно иронично, что двое активных участников меты получили бан)

Comment: ирония запрещена! А кто второй?

Comment: @alexolut AK же. Ему и до этого ещё прилетало сообщение при удалении комнаты.

Comment: сейчас он не забанен. На пару часов что ли было?

Comment: @alexolut не знаю. У него, вероятно, просто причина другая была. Меня за тревоги забанили )

Comment: так я не о причине, а о факте. Athari вот видно на год.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перевели. Сейчас там текст:

> Если команда модераторов не способна решить ваши проблемы, пожалуйста,
>   свяжитесь с командой Stack Overflow.